# While Loop not satisfying conditon

Tags: c++, c

I have written a while loop to run until it find  `*/` . But unfortunately my loop is exiting as soon as it finds a single `*`  itself .

```
while (str[++i] != '*' && str[++i] !='/' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Well, the loop stops as soon as `str[i]` is `*` OR `/`. You'll have to pick another approach - you need a lookahead character to know when the sequence `*/` appears.

Comment: Use std::string and std::find.

Comment: @pmg: Not in this case - the operands of `&&` are sequenced.

Comment: @aschepler too early of me to think. is `||` similarly sequenced?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes - `&&`, `||`, `?`, and `,` as the comma operator (but not as the separator between function arguments).

Comment: Your condition is trying to be too clever. Reduce the cleverness.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem `&&` is sequenced.

Comment: @jrok: nips, right you are. deleted comment, though I still maintain that `strstr`, `strbrk` or `strtok` might be worth a peek, for the OP who is likely to be parsing code

Comment: You've got some good specific answers. A good general piece of advice is: you are trying to do way too much in too little code. Making the code more verbose does not make it slower or use more memory, but it does make it easier for humans to read, understand and maintain the code. Try to have exactly one side effect per statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your loop condition and at what you expect the code to do, it is clearly wrong. A while loop stops as soon as its condition is false, this means that it will stop when this is true:

```
!(str[++i] != '*' && str[++i] !='/')
```

Which is the same as `(str[++i] == '*' || str[++i] =='/')`. It stops as soon as it hits a `*` because of short circuit evaluation. Also, the double increment side-effects are quite subtle to handle and can lead to hard to track bugs.

You are also missing the check for end of string. I'd advice to do something like:

```
while (str[i] != '\0' && !(str[i] == '*' && str[i+1] =='/')) {
    i++;
}
```

Or, equivalently,

```
for (; str[i] != '\0' && !(str[i] == '*' && str[i+1] =='/'); i++)
    ; /* Intentionally left blank. */
```

Answer (score 3):

there are several problems with this construct:

```
while (str[++i] != '*' && str[++i] !='/' );
```

- You don't stop if the string ends and no */ is found.
- The loop will stop if either a `*` or a `/` is found.

You can do it like this:

```
while (str[i]) {
    if (str[i] == '*' && str[i+1] =='/' ) {
        break;
    }
    i++
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyLambert `while (str[++i])` will stop when `str[++i] == '\0'`.

Comment: True, but the code can still access the string past the terminator if it's an empty string.

Comment: There is another problem with my suggested solution: It won't work if */ is first in the string. Fixed it!

Comment: @jrok You are right, I'll remove that part from my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

What about using the function:

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

[Strstr Docs.](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/string_h/strstr.php)

```
char *substr = strstr ( &str[i], "*/" );
```

I don't know what your bigger picture is but usually parsing is done by breaking up 'keywords' separated by 'white space' into an array of tokens. "*/" would then be one of your tokens. You might find the C function strtok worth checking out.